# How to center my div in responsive design way?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a text-align center in my elements and I want everything inside that element has text-align left.

Here is my html

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='inside-wrapper'>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>

#inside-wrapper{
  text-align:center;
}

#inside-wrapper div{
  display:inline-block
  text-align:left;
}
```

The above codes don't work and I need to center my elements like this

```
 ----------------------
|
|    test test test    //inside-wrapper is center but elements inside inside-wrapper is  
|    test              //text-align left            
|
```

I could use `margin:0 auto` and setup width for the `inside-wrapper` but I am also doing responsive design so I can't really set the width in my `inside-wrapper`. How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you draw an example of exactly what is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the alignment of elements:

1. The `text-align` propertly only applies to text or `inline-block` elements (like `span` or `a`), not `block` elements (like `div` or `p`).

I think this is what you're looking for:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Outer">
    <div id="Inner">
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Outer {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#Inner div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check the [**jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6yXx/).

As you may notice, you can use the `auto` property to align elements horizontally **but** you'll need to specify an specific `margin-top` size in order to center the inner element vertically; the overflow property must also be set to `hidden`, otherwise the margin will push your div down.

**Update**:

If you don't need to vertically center your inner div, you can stick with this (the inner-div's width is also relative), [**check this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6yXx/1/):

**CSS**:

```
#Outer {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Inner {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    background: red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#Inner div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

By default, all `div`'s widths are set to `100%` and their heights to wrap their contents, so if you need to center your div without havning to set its width, you should do something like this:

**CSS**:

```
#Outer {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

#Inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#Inner div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In this case you can center your inner div with the text-align property but you'll need to set its display property to `inline-block`. Check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6yXx/5/).

Comment: Thanks but I can't have the set width for the Outer and Inner div because I am doing the responsive design. +1

Comment: I used the fixed size because of the vertical alignment, but if you don't need to center your inner div vertically you should be good with the horizonal margins set to auto approach.

Comment: hm..I am not quiet understand what you mean. Could you please have updated jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working, if you just fix the missing semicolon after `display: inline-block`

```
#inside-wrapper div{
  display:inline-block; // Missing semicolon here.
  text-align:left;
}
```

As for the last child being centered, you could easily use pseudo selector `:last-child`, to float the div left.

[Your Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E4AM/)